# calculate the time logged in by a user

Tags: php

i want to calculate the time for which the user remains logged in on my site, for example if user A logs in at 10 am and logs off at 10:15 am then store 15 minutes time and if he again logs in then also calculate that time and add to this 15 minutes and shows his total time in the system.

Comment: there is no perfect system to do that. Your options are: do ajax javascript calls on background to log every minute or Have a javascript that executes whenever a page is closed.

Comment: thanks @Dimi... but logging each and every minute is a costly operation i believe... what say??

Comment: the way I think would be to record the unix time when logging in in a variable and then when loggin off in the second one. Then you make a simple calcul to get the difference which would be the result in seconds. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Quick example I can give you.

First add the required field in your database. i.e. In your users table, have a field called 'totalTime' or something.

If you're using SESSIONS, keep a value $_SESSION["start_time"] when the user logs in, and when the user logs out take the difference of the current time subtracted by the start time and add it to the totalTime field in the database for the specified user.

Any variation of that should work.

Comment: if user does not logout and session timesout then there is no way to record it.

Comment: @Dimi You're right, but in the question he specifies that he wants the time for which the user "remains logged in" until when the user logs off.

But you're absolutely right, in the general case this would not work.

Comment: @dimi..actually thats a good question...  in this session can we do anything using session time out?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a **loggedIn** field in your table, and a **totalTime** field. When the user logs in, record the time in the loggedIn field. When he logs out, get the logged in time, calculate the difference, and store it in the totalTime field, and zero the loggedIn field.

If the user logs in and the **loggedIn** field is not zero, the user did not log out, add the difference between the current time and the last **loggedIn** value can be added to the **totalTime** (or zero added - you would decide on a policy) and the **loggedIn** field updated to the new log in time etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect detailed information about users, and not use simple statistics that google paralytics provide, you have a couple options, none of which are perfect solutions for anything.

Option 1:
You can simply record the time when users click on your page. The issue with this is that there is no way to see how much time a user has spent on your last page. But overall it will provide a good estimate, but will be very costly if yo have over 1000 users.

Option 2: 
Record the time when user enters the website, and then have javascript ajax call that will record the time when user either logs out or closes the page. This will work if you allow users to be in a single window only.

Option 3:
Have javascript execute every minute or so and tell database that user is still logged in. Almost all databases can do over 1000 queries like that per second. If you optimize it, change database engine or do anything else you can easily get to 10k-25k queries per second.

Option 3:
If you are charging people money per minute then you can wrap the entire thing in java, or flash. however it is also not very secure.

Bottom line is: There is no perfect way to do it. You will have to hope that users have javascript enabled and track their time using background scripts, or do the whole session thing and hope that users log out. Or Track everything click by click and hope that your algorithm works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution would be the most efficient one

1. The log table should have userid, unique_identifier, start_time, end_time
2. Logging in to the website will add a unique identifier for that session. It can be random number of 12 digits.
3. A variable $default_duration =  1440; is defined to calculate the session exipry due to inactivity. This variable should be set according to your server settings. 1140 is 1140 seconds (24 minutes), which is the default session exipry time
4. On user login, lets say a user loggs in by 2PM, the end time is set on login as well, which will be 2.24PM. This will solve the scenario of a user's session expiry due to inactivity.
5. On each page load, the end time is updated with "Current Time + $default_duration"
6. If a user clicks on Logout button, the endtime for that session is taken from the current time. This records the exact duration of the user.
7. Incase if the user logout and logins again, it would have a different "unique identifier" and the log time is updated against it.